# autodoc for Clojure and emacs

Tags: emacs, clojure

I think I had a setup sometimes where the Clojure doc string was displayed in the Emacs statusbar if the cursor was on a symbol that had a doc string. This setup is lost and I have completely forgotten what I configured to make this work and even Google couldn't help.

Answer (score 1):

eldoc mode and  (add-hook 'cider-mode-hook #'eldoc-mode) was the solution.